# Is AsyncTask's Thread Pool managed by the application or the android os?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

As we know android's AsyncTask is executing on a thread pool of limited size.
Is this thread pool unique per application ? 
For example if I set an AsyncTask for execution will the application create the thread pool needed or it will use a thread pool managed from the android operating system?

Comment: For every application, the DVM spawns a separate virtual Machine and the address space is unique. That in my opinion is managed by the OS.

Comment: AFAIK every DVM creates a unique thread pool per application. As a logical result, this will limit the threads per application. The OS will only make a native Thread if one Thread of this thread pool is used. The native Threads are handled by the scheduler of the OS. That's because an OS should only now about threads if they are running and don't care how many "placeholders" per application are used.